# How to process ASM files in Spark (Python/Scala)

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, assembly

First, Below is the sample line from ASM file which contains 1-2 millions lines like this:

```
.text:0040120F 03 CA                                   add     ecx, edx
.text:00401211 89 48 3C                                mov     [eax+3Ch], ecx
.text:00401214 8B 0D C4 7E 58 00                           mov     ecx, dword_587EC4
```

I want to count the Header(text) and Segments(add, mov) in each file in Spark for fast processing. I've read documentations/articles but didn't found any techniques to analyze files line by line to count only these headers, segments.

After Processing the result should be:

```
'text': 3,
'add': 1,
'mov': 2
```

**Is there anyway to extract only these parts from assembly files In Spark?**

Comment: What is the total size of the files you want to process? Are you sure you need Spark for this?

Comment: 136 GB with 11,000 .asm files. I've used Python with multiprocessing for it but file > 50mb takes 5,6 minutes for just one file that's why want to use Spark for fast processing

Comment: Have you tried to profile? What's the bottleneck?

Comment: bottleneck is time.. python code is taking more than 5 minutes for 1 file which is not realistic to run on the whole data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem size**

Let's assume each line of the assembly file takes 200 bytes of data.
A file of 50 MB then roughly has 250,000 lines, and with 5.6 minutes to process them all, that gives a processing time per line of 1 to 1.5 ms. It is rather high but let's keep it unchallenged. At this rate, processing 136 GB would take 10 and a half days.

**Map/reduce with Spark**

Under these assumptions, a map-reduce seems welcome indeed, and hopefully Spark can help. I do not know which infrastructure you are using to run your Spark jobs so the following focuses on the code processing the lines of the ASM file and remains very generic.

First, let's implement the logic to extract the information from each line individually.

```
val regex = "\\.(.*):(?:[A-Z0-9]+\\s)+\\s+([a-z]+).*".r

def parse(line: String) = {
  line match {
    case regex(header, instruction) => Seq(header, instruction)
    case _ => Seq()
  }
}
```

Now we need to create an RDD from the assembly files, with something like

```
val rdd = sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://path/file1,hdfs://path/file2,...")
```

Or if you want to read all the files from a directory:

```
val rdd = sparkContext.textFile("hdfs://path/*")
```

And write the actual map/reduce to extract the frequencies of the line header and ASM instructions:

```
val frequencies = rdd.flatMap(parse _).map((_, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

**Tests and results**

I tested it in a `spark-shell` with the three lines in your example:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ".text:0040120F 03 CA                    add     ecx, edx",
  ".text:00401211 89 48 3C                 mov     [eax+3Ch], ecx",
  ".text:00401214 8B 0D C4 7E 58 00        mov     ecx, dword_587EC4"
))
```

And displayed the output with:

```
frequencies.foreach(x => println(x._1 + ":" + x._2))
```

This gave

```
mov:2
add:1
text:3
```

**Notes**

The ad-hoc "parsing" logic is based on what I understood from the problem statement but I guess it will need to be adapted for your use case.

Comment: Yes its working with  `sc.parallelize(Seq())` but please clarify how to use this function with `WholeTextFile()` object. `parse()` function needs `RDD[String]` but `WholeTextFile()` create `RDD[String][String]`. I've tried `.map(_._2)` but it counts and prints nothing. And Thanks for help.

Comment: @MHarisKhan Sure - so to make it more tailored to your use case, where are the files stored?

Comment: i've upload the files to HDFS and now reading from HDFS in spark code.

Comment: @MHarisKhan ok - I updated my post. Try `textFile` instead with a comma-separated list of files - or use the wildchar `*` if you want to select a directory.

Comment: @MHarisKhan Fixed my code - there is no `sc` after `sparkContext`

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks @AlexandreDupriez :)

Comment: Great, I am glad it helped!